# CASE Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

just a curious question. I have written following code using CASE statement but I don't have data so I am not sure if my logic is correct. All I am doing is I am applying length check on each field and if it doesn't match then put it in error table. So, can anybody just tell me if my logic is correct?

Query:

```
 INSERT INTO
                [Elig].[dbo].[ErrorTable]
                (
                 [SeqId],
                 [CodeId],
                 [SubjectArea],
                 [FieldName],
                 [TableName],
                 [ErrorValue],
                 [ActiveFlag]
                )
                SELECT
                    [sd].[SuscriberDataId] AS [SeqId],
                    @InvalidLength AS [CodeId],
                    @SubjectArea AS [SubjectArea],
            CASE WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberNumber]))) > 9 THEN 'SubscriberNumber'
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberLastName]))) > 35 THEN 'SubscriberLastName'
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberFirstName]))) > 15 THEN 'SubscriberFirstName'
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberMiddleInitial]))) > 1 THEN 'SubscriberMiddleInitial'  
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Sex]))) > 1 THEN 'Sex'
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Dob]))) > 8 THEN 'Dob'   
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Ssn]))) > 9 THEN 'Ssn'
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[FacetsGroup]))) > 8 THEN 'FacetsGroup'  
           END AS FieldName,
           'Eligibility.SubscriberData',
           CASE  WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberNumber]))) > 9 THEN [SubscriberNumber]
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberLastName]))) > 35 THEN [SubscriberLastName]
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberFirstName]))) > 15 THEN [SubscriberFirstName]
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberMiddleInitial]))) > 1 THEN [SubscriberMiddleInitial]  
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Sex]))) > 1 THEN [Sex]
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Dob]))) > 8 THEN [Dob]   
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Ssn]))) > 9 THEN [Ssn]
                 WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[FacetsGroup]))) > 8 THEN [FacetsGroup]  
           END AS ErrorValue,           
           @ActiveFlag AS [ActiveFlag]
           FROM [Eligibility].[SubscriberData]
           WHERE len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberNumber]))) > 9 OR
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberLastName]))) > 35 OR
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberFirstName]))) > 15 OR
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[SubscriberMiddleInitial]))) > 1 OR  
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Sex]))) > 1 OR
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Dob]))) > 8 OR   
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[Ssn]))) > 9 OR
                 len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd].[FacetsGroup]))) > 8
```

Comment: just wanna make sure is my logic correct?

Comment: Anyway, CASE seems wrong way here - you should use OR statement, otherwise most errors go unnoticed.

Comment: the whole thing is repeated 3 times, and WHEN len(ltrim(Rtrim([sd]. is repeated like 20 times.  This is not good until those numbers are waay down

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply. can u explain that with a code so i can better understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your source table should be defined so that each field cannot be larger than the defined maximum.  I am therefore guessing (hoping) that this is a bit of a one-off exercise to identify bad data and fix it, before fixing the underlying table definition.

As @Matt commented, lots of `len(ltrim(rtrim(` in here, which is going to make this slow.

And as @Arvo points out, you will only log the first error in each row - e.g. if `SubscriberNumber` and `SubscriberLastName` are both too long, only `SubscriberNumber` will get logged.

You should ensure your data is trimmed when writing it.  This will remove the need to `ltrim(rtrim(` all over the shop.  If necessary, run a one-off query across your table to fix the existing data values.

Your `where` clause is probably as efficient as it's going to be (once you lose all those trims), and could be used either to drive a cursor or to populate a temp table that you can then query several times - once for each field check.

The latter solution might look like this.  First get the rows that have errors:

```
SELECT
     [sd].[SuscriberDataId]
    ,[sd].[SubscriberNumber]
    ,[sd].[SubscriberLastName]
    ,[sd].[SubscriberFirstName]
    ,[sd].[SubscriberMiddleInitial]
    ,[sd].[Sex]
    ,[sd].[Dob]
    ,[sd].[Ssn]
    ,[sd].[FacetsGroup]
INTO #temp
FROM [Eligibility].[SubscriberData] [sd]
WHERE
    len([sd].[SubscriberNumber]) > 9 OR
    len([sd].[SubscriberLastName]) > 35 OR
    len([sd].[SubscriberFirstName]) > 15 OR
    len([sd].[SubscriberMiddleInitial]) > 1 OR  
    len([sd].[Sex]) > 1 OR
    len([sd].[Dob]) > 8 OR   
    len([sd].[Ssn]) > 9 OR
    len([sd].[FacetsGroup]) > 8
```

Then, for one field at a time, get the rows which break the rules:

```
-- SubscriberNumber check
INSERT INTO [Elig].[dbo].[ErrorTable]
    (
        [SeqId],
        [CodeId],
        [SubjectArea],
        [FieldName],
        [TableName],
        [ErrorValue],
        [ActiveFlag]
    )

SELECT
    [t].[SuscriberDataId],
    @InvalidLength,
    @SubjectArea,
    'SubscriberNumber',
    'Eligibility.SubscriberData',
    [t].[SubscriberNumber],
    @ActiveFlag
FROM #temp
WHERE len([t].[SubscriberNumber]))) > 9
```

Repeat for the next field, etc.